# I am getting xhr.js:247 error on the mobile device while on the other hand the server is running perfectly on the Desktop

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to  gett all the products, categories and subcategories from the backend to frontend on **"/"** path
When I first Accessed the webiste on the mobile on `http://192.168.143.4:3000/`. I encountered the websocket error

WebSocket connection to `ws://127.0.0.1:50847/` failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

But after some time it was gone, I don't know how but that error still comes. Then I am constantly getting error on the mobile phone is

```
http://localhost:5000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

dispatchXhrRequest  @   xhr.js:247

xhr @   xhr.js:49

dispatchRequest @   dispatchRequest.js:51

request @   Axios.js:142

Axios.<computed>    @   Axios.js:168

wrap    @   bind.js:5

getHomeData @   api.js:12

getData @   Layout.js:18

(anonymous) @   Layout.js:45

commitHookEffectListMount   @   react-dom.development.js:23150

commitPassiveMountOnFiber   @   react-dom.development.js:24926

commitPassiveMountEffects_complete  @   react-dom.development.js:24891

commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @   react-dom.development.js:24878

commitPassiveMountEffects   @   react-dom.development.js:24866

flushPassiveEffectsImpl @   react-dom.development.js:27039

flushPassiveEffects @   react-dom.development.js:26984

performSyncWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:26076

flushSyncCallbacks  @   react-dom.development.js:12042

commitRootImpl  @   react-dom.development.js:26959

commitRoot  @   react-dom.development.js:26682

finishConcurrentRender  @   react-dom.development.js:25981

performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @   react-dom.development.js:25809

workLoop    @   scheduler.development.js:266

flushWork   @   scheduler.development.js:239

performWorkUntilDeadline
```

One thing I have noticed more is that request headers are different on the mobile and desktop
Here is the request Header on the desktop
[Resonse Header on Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruaC5.png)

This is response header on the mobile device
[Response Header on the mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlFKq.png)

this is my code Index.js backend

```
const app = express();
const corsOptions = {
  origin: [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://192.168.143.4:3000",
    "http://192.168.1.194:3000",
  ],
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", router);
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Listening at 5000");
});
```

Layout.js where I am getting data

```
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(MyContext);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [categoriesData, setCategoriesData] = useState({});
  const [subcategoriesData, setSubCategoriesData] = useState({});
  const [productData, setProductData] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await getHomeData();
        const categories = result?.data?.categories;
        const subcategories = result?.data?.subcategories;
        const products = result?.data?.products;
        setCategoriesData(categories);
        setSubCategoriesData(subcategories);
        setProductData(products);
        dispatch({ type: 'ADD_DATA_TO_PRODUCTS', payload: products});
        dispatch({ type: 'ADD_DATA_TO_CATEGORIES', payload: categories});
        dispatch({ type: 'ADD_DATA_TO_SUBCATEGORIES', payload: subcategories});
        allDataCon(categories, subcategories, products);
      } catch (error) {
        console.info(error);
      }
    };

    const allDataCon = (categories, subcategories, products) => {
      if(categories && subcategories && products){
        setIsLoading(false)
      }
    };

    getData();
  }
```